# MPICH: MPICC ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker-errors, mpich

I just installed MPICH on my mac with brew. And I'm trying to compile code.

```
MacBook-Air:~ ali$ cd Desktop/mpitest
MacBook-Air:mpitest ali$ mpicc mpi_prime.c -o mpi_prime
ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried mpiexec hostname and it works just fine.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you don't have `gfortran` installed. That should probably have triggered when you were building the homebrew version, but I've noticed that they've started using more pre-built versions. You might try installing `gfortran` manually and seeing if that fixes things.

Comment: run "brew doctor". I had the same error and brew told me to run "brew link gcc" which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the switch from gcc 4.9 to gcc 5 break path to the Fortran 3 lib. I have the same problem with R:

```
metalpro2:~ mirkoebert$ R
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.0/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

R references the Fortran 3 lib in the gcc 4 directory.

The solution with **brew**:

1. you need gcc 4.9 and 5.X, installed via brew
2. link your new lib into the old gcc folder:

`ln -s /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dy lib/usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib`

Now it works for R.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as @tfb785, but his solution did not work for me. I already had gcc 4.9.2_1 and 5, but I had to tell brew to switch between the versions:

```
brew switch gcc 4.9.2_1
```

Comment: Solve the switch your problem?

Comment: Partially...I had a couple of other issues that needed resolving, but yes, it got R running.